# auto login in a site with other user account

Tags: php, security, networking, modx

I am having a weird problem. I have a website. It was running well for 2 or more years. Today I have got a problem. Sometimes when any user reloading any page around 2 to 10 times it is showing the user is logged in with another user account.

I used modx cms for this website.

I don't know much about security. Could anyone explain me why this could be happening?
Let me know if any information needed.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some more information on your website? What framework was used to write the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, my **wild guess** would be that the backend is written poorly and that only the last used logged in is remembered. That would mean that there are no sessions i.e. the last user logged in is the one that is displayed.

If this is really so, that it's a bad mistake. However, this is only a guess based on what you said. I quite sure that the problem is *something else*, but to find out what, more information would be needed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. this problem was not occur last 2 years.Suddenly it is happening. so i think it is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

It way the server issue because as you told that the site is well running from last 2 year.